# Gap between letters in html email in Outlook 2010

Tags: outlook, html-email

Randomly seeing gaps appearing between letters in words when viewing emails in someone's Outlook 2010. The same email looks fine in my Outlook 2016 and web-based clients. Any suggestions?

[image: Gap in word in email]

Comment: _Has anyone ever seen this before?..._ Yes I have....I love these binary questions....However your question doesn't fit into SO rules....Please **visit** the **[help center](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and take the tour to see what and how to ask...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have re-worded the question.

Comment: I am assuming that somewhere in your code you have a rule for `mso-wordbreak` which we could verify if you would please post your code. Thank you!

Comment: I suppose showing the actual html code is unpossible. Does this happen with every email or just that one email? If it's every one, it sounds like an issue with that install of Outlook.

Comment: Looks like it could be due to line length exceeding the limit, so now trying to find a library that can handle this